# How I can Delete Footer without using plugin BlankSlate?

Tags: footer

can anybody know how I can delete footer without using plugin BlakSlate? This plugin aswel delete my header, but I need header. I want to just delete or hide footer row/area. Please help and thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

Forget this plugin and just hide the footer with css :

At the end of your theme style.css, just add this :

```
#footer{display:none;}
```

Bases on the fact that your footer isg à div with `id="footer"`